# Firebase with Facebook and User/Password Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm implementing facebook login with firebase for my application. The objective is to develop a logic that the user can login with email/password provider or facebook provider. As i started developing, i found two ways to do what i want:

1 - Link facebook to email/password provider:

- User has to be logged in with email/password to make this happen. Which means, if the user is not logged in, i don't have a reference (current user) to link the facebook provider. User cannot sign up with facebook provider because the email is already being used by another provider (email/password).

2 - Enable multiple accounts with the same email on firebase:

- User can sign up with facebook and email/password. But firebase won't register the facebook data for the email/password provider. Which means, when i try to get the email from the current user, i have to specify the provider that have the email attribute (facebook provider). Email/password provider returns an empty email

  `final String email = firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(1).getEmail();`

**Conclusion**

- The first way won't work for me. User may not be logged in all the time. He may want to login in different ways. I don't want the user to insert his password for email/password provider just to link to his facebook provider.
- If i choose the second way, i can't find a way to update the email attribute for email/password provider. And it wouldn't be a good practice to always check what providers the user have, just to specify which provider to get the email from.

Is there something i'm missing? I tried using updateEmail() when user signs up with facebook but it just updates the email attribute for facebook provider. Do i really have to make the user insert his password to create a link between the two providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the convenience of user profile information being provided by methods such as `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect()` and `firebase.auth().linkWithRedirect()`, then the Firebase project needs to be configured with **`One account per email address`** (`Firebase Console > Authentication > Sign-in method`). This is the simplest (and default) configuration.

The original question stated:

> I don't want the user to insert his password for email/password provider just to link to his facebook provider.

- If a user consistently signs in using the same provider method (e.g. Facebook, password, email link, Google Sign-in) then he/she will never need to link accounts.
- **For users that want to sign-in using multiple providers, account linking is a straightforward user experience and only happens one time when first linking providers.**

## Linking Accounts

- When the Firebase project is configured with **`One account per email address`**, then the first time a user attempts to sign-in with a different provider, you will receive the Firebase error `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential`.
- Resolve this by calling [`firebase.auth.Auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) and then asking the user to sign in using one of the returned providers.
- Once the user is signed in, the original credential can be linked to the user with [`firebase.User.linkWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#linkwithcredential)

Note that account linking works for any combination of providers. Hence, it doesn't matter if a user first signs-up using email/password and then later decides to sign-in with Facebook or vice versa.

Comment: This works unless they don't first have an Email account.  The following is incorrect: `Note that account linking works for any combination of providers. Hence, it doesn't matter if a user first signs-up using email/password and then later decides to sign-in with Facebook or vice versa`.  If they create account with facebook, then try to sign in with their email, they will get a `auth/wrong-password` error, which is much more complex to deal with.